# Interactively update color in Mayavi, Python

Tags: python, traits, mayavi

It is my first post on StackOverflow.
I am writing a **Mayavi Python** program.  Could anybody tell me how to update/modify the color of a point interactively?  For example, in `points3d()`, changing the color of a point in real-time when I interactively modify its position.
I tried to do something under `@on_trait_change`, but it doesn't work.  Color cannot be changed.
The following is my code:

```
import mayavi
import mayavi.mlab
from numpy import arange, pi, cos, sin

from traits.api import HasTraits, Range, Instance, \
        on_trait_change
from traitsui.api import View, Item, HGroup

from mayavi.core.api import PipelineBase
from mayavi.core.ui.api import MayaviScene, SceneEditor, \
                MlabSceneModel

def luc_func(x, y, z):
    return x + y + z;

class Visualization(HasTraits):
    x1 = Range(1, 30, 5)
    z1 = Range(1, 30, 5)
    scene      = Instance(MlabSceneModel, ())
    def __init__(self):
        # Do not forget to call the parent's __init__
        HasTraits.__init__(self)
        z = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
        y = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5]
        x = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
        self.plot = self.scene.mlab.points3d(x, y, z, luc_func, scale_mode = 'none')
        #self.plot2 = self.scene.mlab.points3d(z, x, y, color = (0, 0, 1))

    @on_trait_change('x1,z1')
    def update_plot(self):
        x = [1,2,3,4,self.x1,1,2,3,4,self.x1,1,2,3,4,self.x1,1,2,3,4,self.x1,1,2,3,4,self.x1]
        z = [1,1,1,1,self.z1,1,1,1,1,self.z1,1,1,1,1,self.z1,1,1,1,1,self.z1,1,1,1,1,self.z1]
        luc_func = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,self.z1]
        self.plot.mlab_source.reset(x = x, z = z, luc_func = luc_func)
        #self.plot2.mlab_source.set(y = y, z = z)


    # the layout of the dialog created
    view = View(Item('scene', editor=SceneEditor(scene_class=MayaviScene),
                    height=250, width=300, show_label=False),
                HGroup(
                        '_', 'x1', "z1",
                    ),
                )
visualization = Visualization()
visualization.configure_traits()
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! What does "but it doesn't work" means? Do you get any error messages? Please describe it more detailed.

Comment: Hi Bish, Thanks for your notification, I will edit my description later!  Well, the problem can work, but the color cannot be changed.  i.e. only positions could be modified

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed a bug in the interactivity of `points3d` very similar to what you are describing here. I don't know exactly what is the origin of this bug but I regularly use the following workaround. The basic idea is to avoid `mlab.points3d` and instead call `mlab.pipeline.glyph` directly, as in:

```
def virtual_points3d(coords, figure=None, scale_factor=None, color=None, 
    name=None):

    c = np.array(coords)
    source = mlab.pipeline.scalar_scatter( c[:,0], c[:,1], c[:,2],
        figure=figure)

    return mlab.pipeline.glyph( source, scale_mode='none', 
        scale_factor=scale_factor,
        mode='sphere', figure=figure, color=color, name=name)
```

Later you can change the colors by referring to the vtk object directly, rather than the mayavi trait that isn't connected properly:

```
glyph = virtual_points3d(coords)
glyph.mlab_source.dataset.point_data.scalars = new_values
```

Comment: Hi aestrivex,  thanks for your help!  I will study your code and try it later!